# adding TextMode attribute to a textbox results in removal of all styles from the textbox

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html

Hello guys I am making a login form where i want the txtpassword textbox to have

TextMode="password" but as soon as I add this attribute all my styles are gone I want to know how can i hide the password (instead show dot like characters) and also have styles applied here is my code if you guys need

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <%--this runs perfectly--%>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<%--styles aren't there as soon as i add TextMode or type attributes--%>
```

Comment: what kind of styles are you talking about here? CSS or Asp.net Style ?

Comment: Post the css that you use..Problem might be with css

Comment: You can check the answer to that similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936431/css-not-working-when-textbox-mode-changed-as-password